# Common idea in Karatsuba, Gauss and Strassen multiplication

Tags: algorithms, matrices

The identities used in multiplication algorithms by

- [Karatsuba](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm#The_basic_step) (integers)
- [Gauss](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm#Gauss.27s_complex_multiplication_algorithm) (complex numbers)
- [Strassen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strassen_algorithm) (matrices)

seem very closely related. Is there a common abstract framework/generalization?

Comment: Look up Schönhage's asymptotic sum inequality.

Comment: Which identities are you talking about? Are we supposed to read all three articles in order to answer? Please add the relevant information to your question.

Comment: @Raphael: The identities which are foundations for the algorithms, expressing 4 number multiplications with 3 multiplications, and 8 matrix multiplications with 7.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The classical framework is the one of bilinear algorithms and tensor rank decompositions; basically, you construct the 3-way tensor associated to the bilinear map $f(A,B) = A \cdot B$, in the basis of the coefficients, then look for a decomposition of it as a sum of rank-one tensors (i.e., those of the form $T_{i,j,k} = u_i v_j w_k$). You'll find this explained in more detail, for instance, in this [article by Bläser](https://theoryofcomputing.org/articles/gs005/gs005.pdf), or in the book by Bürgisser, Clausen, Shokrollahi, *Algebraic Complexity Theory*.

As far as I understand, the reformulation in terms of group respresentations that Suresh mentions in his answer is a later one, and I find it less suitable for a first approach to the subject (but, of course, that might be bias on my part).

Comment: This is the correct answer. One aspect which is missing is the tensorization / divide-and-conquer which is behind both Karatsuba's algorithm and fast (square) matrix multiplication algorithms.

Answer (score 8):

A partial answer to your question is the group-theoretic approach first developed by [Cohn and Umans](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0307321) and further developed by Cohn, Kleinberg, Szegedy and Umans. It can "sort of" capture Strassen and Coppersmith-Winograd for matrix multiplication.

Comment: This really misses the point. The group theoretic approach is really just one way of coming up with such identities in the first place.